# Why does the `PURE` define "confuse" Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor, intellisense

I noticed that specifying an empty `PURE` define in front of a function confuses Intellisense in VS2015. At the same time, and other non-uppercase combination of the letters (`pure`, `Pure`, `PurE`) works:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define SOME
#define PURE
#define Pure
#define STUFF

// upper case "PURE" 
SOME PURE STUFF uint8_t Add(uint8_t a, uint8_t b)
{
    return (uint8_t)(a + b);
}

// pascal case "Pure"
SOME Pure STUFF uint8_t Sub(uint8_t a, uint8_t b)
{
    return (uint8_t)(a - b);
}
```

It turns out that Intellisense doesn't show the comment for a function marked with `PURE`, and in some cases (not exactly sure which, but when the function is in a separate file) the "Go to Definition (F12)" function doesn't work at all. If I rename `PURE` to `Pure`, it works.

Note the commentless tooltip here:

[image: Specifying PURE confuses VS]

versus the correct Intellisense tooltip here:

[image: Other macros work fine]

Btw, the reason why I am doing this because code is shared between GCC and MSVC, so `PURE` is `__attribute__((pure))` in GCC, for example. So now it seems I will have to change existing GCC codebase to be able to use F12 in Visual Studio, unless I am doing something wrong.

Is this some predefined macro which is somehow messing with Intellisense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied your shared code and I tested it in the VS 2015 and 2017, I found the result in VS 2017 can popup the comment for ‘PURE’ which meet your requirement, please check this:
[image]

You can try to download and install the VS 2017 from [Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) or report this issue in VS 2015 to the VS Product Team at [this page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/LoadSubmitFeedbackForm) to seek for a more professional support.

Comment: Oh, it's you again. :) Time for me to switch then perhaps. Thanks!